# Matlab Cluster outline - cluster 'convex' hull

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I want to plot an outline to a cluster of data points and I am wondering if there is a matlab function that already exists that can do this? Normally "convexhull" is good enough for me for cases when there isn't such prominent clustering, but in the example below, it is clearly unusable.

For example, is there a function that takes a bunch of data points and cluster them based on a tolerance value that I can set? Even better, is there a function that can provide me with an outline that isnt necessarily convex, but instead shrinks the convexhull to be tighter based on a tolerance value. I could probably write my own solution in several hours, but it seems like a very useful thing application that others would have done before, I just dont know what it's called or the keywords to search.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmHE2.png]

Comment: Maybe [`kmeans`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) can be useful

Comment: MathWorks have quite a lot of documentation on [cluster analysis](https://uk.mathworks.com/discovery/cluster-analysis.html) because it's a big topic in machine learning - as Luis suggested a common approach would be to use `kmeans`. If you are still stuck, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I would threshold the results of `pdist` based on your tolerance to generate an adjacency matrix, then pass that to `conncomp` to find the connected components. You can then find the convex hull for each connected component.

Comment: kmeans requires me to know how many clusters to create, which is not useful to me

Comment: @beaker this works, thanks